# Appending a list into another list at various levels

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with three levels.

```
list = {{{7, 5, 8}, {4, 8, 9}, {7, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 4}, {5, 1, 2}}};
```

And I want to put in a list {e,x,y} at the end of every element.

```
Append[Riffle[#, {{e, x, y}}] & /@ list, {e, x, y}]
```

Gives:

```
{{{7, 5, 8}, {e, x, y}, {4, 8, 9}, {e, x, y}, {7, 0, 1}, {e, x, 
   y}, {3, 0, 4}, {e, x, y}, {5, 1, 2}}, {e, x, y}}
```

1. There is that {e,x,y} missing at the end.
2. How do I group every two elements together to get:

```
{{{7, 5, 8, e, x, y}, {4, 8, 9, e, x, y}, {7, 0, 1, e, x, 
   y}, {3, 0, 4, e, x, y}, {5, 1, 2, e, x, y}}}
```

Is there is function to do it in one line?

Answer (score 1):

```
Map[Join[#, {e, x, y}] &, list, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{7, 5, 8, e, x, y}, {4, 8, 9, e, x, y}, {7, 0, 1, e, x, y}, 
> {3, 0, 4, e, x, y}, {5, 1, 2, e, x, y}}}
> ```

Also

```
list /. {a__Integer} :> {a, e, x, y}

Map[Flatten[Riffle[{#}, {{e, x, y}}]] &, list, {2}]

Map[PadRight[#, Length@# + 3, {e, x, y}] &, list, {2}]

List @ ArrayPad[First@list, {{0}, {0, 3}}, {{e, x, y}}]

Flatten[Outer[Join, First@list, {{e, x, y}}, 1], {2}]

List @ (Join @@@ Tuples[{First@list, {{e, x, y}}}])

List[Join @@@ Thread[{First@list, {e, x, y}}, List, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
list={{{7,5,8},{4,8,9},{7,0,1},{3,0,4},{5,1,2}}};
{Join[#,{e,x,y}]&/@list[[1]]}
```

which returns

```
{{{7,5,8,e,x,y},{4,8,9,e,x,y},{7,0,1,e,x,y},{3,0,4,e,x,y},{5,1,2,e,x,y}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html):

```
m = {{7, 5, 8}, {4, 8, 9}, {7, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 4}, {5, 1, 2}};

ArrayFlatten[{{m, e, x, y}}]
```

> ```
> {{7, 5, 8, e, x, y},
>  {4, 8, 9, e, x, y},
>  {7, 0, 1, e, x, y},
>  {3, 0, 4, e, x, y},
>  {5, 1, 2, e, x, y}}
> ```

There is an extra [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) level in both your input and output examples that I dropped as it only obfuscates this operation.  This extra level can be easily added after if needed.

```
{ ArrayFlatten[{Join[list, {e, x, y}]}] }
```

> ```
> {{{7, 5, 8, e, x, y}, {4, 8, 9, e, x, y},
>  {7, 0, 1, e, x, y}, {3, 0, 4, e, x, y}, {5, 1, 2, e, x, y}}}
> ```